# Passing .env file to docker compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I try to specify an external `.env` file using `docker compose up` like this ([docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/#cli)):

```
docker compose -f docker/development/docker-compose.yml --env-file ./.env.development.sample  up -d
```

but the variables such as `DATABASE_URL` as specified in the `./.env.development.sample` are not available in my `node` processes.

Docker terminal output: (the .env file is completely ignored)

```
/app # printenv
NODE_VERSION=18.16.1
HOSTNAME=1df9baa92492
YARN_VERSION=1.22.19
SHLVL=1
PORT=3000
HOME=/root
TERM=xterm
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED=1
PWD=/app
NODE_ENV=development
```

How can I get environment variables into the runtime instance of a container? I don't wanna bake in (build) with a concrete `.env` file.